# In angular $http service, on error, all the parameters are undefied

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a service which in some circumstances it returns 400 status code. in this situation, all the parameters in 'onerror' are undefined. this is my code :

```
This.$http.post(url, data, config)
     .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
          callback(response);
     })
     .error(function (response, status, header, config) {
          onerror(response)
     });
```

I have tried this too :

```
 This.$http.post(url, data, config)
         .then(function successCallback(response) {
              callback(response.data);
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
             onerror(response.data)
    });
```

here, "response" containing errors which show in browser console

```
message:"Unexpected token P in JSON at position 1"
stack:"SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 1↵ 
at      JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at vc (http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:46:367)
at Zb (http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:365:198)
at http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:368:86
at m (http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:11:282)
at dd (http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:368:62)
at d (http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:374:69)
at http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:499:157
at n.$eval (http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:559:56)
at n.$digest     
(http://localhost:8080/server/lib/angular/angular.min.js:546:90)"
```

data which are return as response is so :

```
"[PARAMETER]
[addFrequentItem.arg1.itemName]
[invalid.item.type]
[value]"
```

I need to access returned status code to handle error. I don't know what the problem is.

**Update :**
i didn't find a good solution in "$http" but instead i replace this code with $http and it works fine :

```
var x = new ActiveXObject();

x.open(method, url, true);
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (x.readyState == 4) {
     if (x.status == 200) {
         callback(JSON.parse(x.responseText));
         return x.responseText;
     }else if (x.status == 400){
         var errMsg = x.responseText.split(']')[2].split('[')[1]; // get error message sent by server
         var result = {"resultCode":1,"respCode":errMsg,"respParams":null,"respMessage":null};
         if (onerror) {
              onerror(result);
         }
     }
         else {
             if (onerror) {
                 onerror(JSON.parse(x.responseText));
              }
        }
      }
}
if (method == 'post') {
    x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
}
x.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

and it works fine.

Comment: The response is no json. Can you provide the `onError` callback ?

Comment: no the response is not json. onError is a callback function which is called and run but its needed parameter is undefined.

Comment: Angular is trying to parse the response as Json and this is not. The server should return some `Content-Type: text/plain` instead of `application/json` in header when the erreur occurs. Can you verify the headers returned by the server ?

Comment: thank you for your answer, no i can't change server side and i have to ask someone else to do so, if it is possible;

Answer (score 1):

I assume, if `$http` success than it have `statusCode`.

if `$http` call success than successsCallback called. under this check proper status is coming or not, if response not coming in your desire format than manually set `statusCode` and `data` as `null`. same follow in errorCallback.

you need to manage `response.statusCode` and `error.code` according to your coming property.

`callback` function call with single parameter with two property `statusCode` and `data`.

```
$http.post(url, data, config).then(
/*successsCallback*/
function(response) { 
    if(response && !isNaN(response.statusCode)) {
        callback({statusCode: response.statusCode, data: response.data});
    }
    else { /* either response is null or response.statusCode is null */
        callback({statusCode: /*manual statusCode*/, data: null});
    }
},
/*errorCallback*/
function(error) {  
    if(error && !isNaN(error.code))
        callback({statusCode: error.code, data: null});
    }
    else { /* either error is null or error.code is null */
        callback(statusCode: /*manual statusCode*/, data: null);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes this could be a solution but in my problem i need 'statusText' too which contain an error message coming from server which could be different.

Comment: @navid you can add `statusText` in callback response like `callback({statusCode: response.statusCode, statusText: /*your statusText*/,  data: response.data})`, according to your error, you must make sure your post configuration content is text/json and server respond with proper json object.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `.then(function successCallback(response) {` instead call

```
$http.post(url, data, config)
.then(function(response) { /*.... do whatever with response...*/})
.catch(function(error) {  /*...do whatever with error ...*/ });
```

or in single callback with comma separated success and error handler function

```
.then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
    },function(error) { 
    console.log(error);
});
```

**alternative:**

or if you have defined `successCallback()` and `errorCallback()`  than call it without parenthesis in then-able block;

```
.then(successCallBack).catch(errorCallback);
```

here I assume that you have defined callback functions with param in below manner

```
var successsCallback = function (result) {
                console.log(result)
};

var errorCallback = function (error) {
                console.log(error)
};
```

Comment: I have tried both of codes which you have written above and unfortunately received same result .

Comment: your response must be in json as it it default in angular. if not than set the `responseType` in `config` paramater of [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: I can not change the response. when i call service using XMLHttpRequest,  in 'x.onreadystatechange' i can access 'status' to see its code. but i think in $http i can't do this !

Comment: as you are sending *config* as 3rd parameter in `$http.post`, there you can set the `responseType: 'text'`

Comment: only in this situation response is string, when there is no error on server response is Json.